# Simple DTMF decoding: find the phone key!

Tags: code-golf, matrix, conversion

This is a simple challenge which hopefully may lead to some creative answers.

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling): *"Dual-tone multi-frequency signaling (DTMF) is an in-band telecommunication signaling system using the voice-frequency band over telephone lines between telephone equipment and other communications devices and switching centers."*

### Task

Given two integers representing the column and row frequencies in the following table, your task is to output the corresponding key:

```
       | 1209 Hz | 1336 Hz | 1477 Hz
-------+---------+---------+---------
697 Hz |    1    |    2    |    3
770 Hz |    4    |    5    |    6
852 Hz |    7    |    8    |    9
941 Hz |    *    |    0    |    #
```

### Examples

- If the input is `[ 1209, 852 ]`, the expected output is "7".
- If the input is `[ 1477, 941 ]`, the expected output is "#".

### Rules

- You must take input as *integers* in any reasonable format, such as two separate variables or an array of two variables. Please specify in which order your program is expecting them (either *column_freq, row_freq* or *row_freq, column_freq*).
- The input is guaranteed to be valid.
- You must print or output a *character*. However, you're also allowed to output an integer for digit keys.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
DḢ×3++6ị9R;“*0#  ”¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l4Y5Fh6cba2ubPdzdbRlk/ahhjpaBsoLCo4a5h5b8P7xc/1HTmsj//6OjzSzNdRQMjQwsY3W4FKA8Y2MzJJ6JuTmYZ25ugKQSwoOphPBgKi1MjZBUQngwlRAeTKWliSGSSggPphLCA6mMBQA)

Takes input as `row`, `column` in two arguments.

This uses `3*<first digit of row> + <column> + 6 % 14` to give a different value for each. This is indexed into `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,"*","0","#"," "," "]` to give the output. The spaces could really be any character; they are just buffer to create an implicit mod 14.

**Low level**

```
DḢ×3++6ị9R;“*0#  ”¤
D                     - digits (of <row>)
 Ḣ                    - head (get first element)
  ×3                  - multiply by 3
    +                 - add (<column>)
     +6               - add 6
       ị              - index into:
                  ¤   - the nilad:
        9R              - range(9)
          ;             - concatenate
           “*0#  ”      - the string "*0#  "
```

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>39</s> 35 bytes

```js
a=>b=>"310*58# 47269"[a%b%83%16%13]
```

Maps the two inputs into numbers in the range `[0, 13)` by calculating:
`col % row % 83 % 16 % 13`.
Takes input in currying syntax (`f(col)(row)`) and returns a single-char string.

### Test Cases

```js
let f=
a=>b=>"310*58# 47269"[a%b%83%16%13]

console.log( f(1336)(941) )
console.log( f(1209)(697) )
console.log( f(1336)(697) )
console.log( f(1477)(697) )
console.log( f(1209)(770) )
console.log( f(1336)(770) )
console.log( f(1477)(770) )
console.log( f(1209)(852) )
console.log( f(1336)(852) )
console.log( f(1477)(852) )
console.log( f(1209)(941) )
console.log( f(1477)(941) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

### History

Started with the range of `[0, 20)` with calculation `col % row % 29 % 20`, which required 8 wasted characters in the mapping.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>42</s> 37 bytes

```
x#y="_1425__#9__*70836"!!mod(2*x+y)18
```

Just some math to index a string. Input order is `<column> # <row>`, e.g. `1336 # 697`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxLCsIwFAD3OcVr4kJrhObTJgF7A3cuQwiFChb7kRqhgd49thu3w8w8m8/r0fcpLSTW2DPJS@@J8T5XhRYVzrJhao88X87xxHQamm6EGtoJAbznbgxwACZERSqjdvQN9zDfRsD4L1i7rdflerGMF4buNmVSKefWuMEtpEoVVJecGsmcQyj9AA)

Edit: @flawr found a formula that works on shorter string. Overall -5 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: I just wrote a little program to optimize your approach, and it appears you can save a few bytes: `x#y="_1425__#9__*70836"!!mod(2*x+y)18`

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 23 bytes

```
13*+79\'186#294*3750'w)
```

Inputs are: column frequency, then row frequency.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39BYS9vcMkbd0MJM2cjSRMvY3NRAvVwTKGFkYMllbm4AAA)

#### Explanation

Multiplying the column frequency by 13, adding the row frequency, and computing modulo 79 gives a different value for each of the 12 pairs of inputs.

```
13*               % First input (implicit) times 13
+                 % Add to second input (implicit)
79\               % Modulo 79
'186#294*3750'    % Push this string
w                 % Swap
)                 % Index
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
%157ị9R;“*0#”¤s3¤ị@⁹%11¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/V0NT84e5uyyDrRw1ztAyUHzXMPbSk2PjQEqCgw6PGnaqGhoeW/P//39LE8L@hibk5AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 34 bytes

```javascript
(a,b)=>'806739214*#5'[a*b%2785%12]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc9LCoMwFIXhuasQimgkLSY@YgZ2I6WD@KBYxJQq3X6a3EHJxWb6w3fgPNVHbcN7fu3nVY@TWaY9HufHvHcmU7Qn3TVti0aUkrMqP9XpTeV9wkVbJ4zfzaDXTS/TZdGPDFTWSEEZLyShsRfKssGhEoKQ6MiFKDCH4HMIId7WHHMIPocQ4rJimEPwOYQj/zfmhqg9@7NuCAc7BCHI7VnMUXDchSC3ZzFHwXEXgtyexRwFx10gUWS@)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda a,b: '806739214*#5'[a*b%2785%12]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc9BCoMwEIXhvacIFNFIFiZRxxR6kraLiNAK1Upx09OnmVmUDLr9mW/grd/t@V5sGKfHtInLLbz8PIxeeDWcRdHXHVhndFOd2uLqqyE30Le5NvewfqZlK4mVnQOlTe2kEkmwtuOhAZAySyFAzSGFFFLYw741HFJIIYU9dI3mkEIKKaSQP0Cs4pz/PWIeIqZwAOMcDllAiOEAxjkcsoAQwwGMczhkASEGmWXhBw)

row,column can be supplied in any order.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 34 bytes

```
&"~"/9-4*&"d"/6-+1g,@
147*2580369#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X02pTknfUtdES00pRUnfTFfbMF3HgcvQxFzLyNTCwNjMUvn/fyDPXMHSxBAA)

Explanation:

```
&"~"/9-4*                (Get number / 126 - 9) * 4 = 0, 4, or 8
         &"d"/6-         Get number / 100 - 6 = 0, 1, 2, or 3
                +        Add the above results - this becomes the x-coordinate in the "lookup table"
                 1g,@    Get a value on row 1 column x, output it, and end
```